# how can i use use local images in my titanium project

Tags: android, mobile, titanium

i'm trying to change my background of a window in titanium , unfortuantly its not working. i also tried to use many local images and they did't load. any help is highly appreciated
,How can use my resources ?

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
title:'Hello',
backgroundImage:'back.png',
});
```

Comment: Set the correct path to your image.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, just like that. `backgroundImage` is supported on window.

Just make sure you use the right path:

```
backgroundImage: Ti.FileSystem.resourcesDirectory + 'back.png'
```

Here I am assuming back.png (case sensitive) is actually in the resources directory root.